# Error Messages when I try to load ggplot2 after installation

Tags: r

I get an error message when I try to load ggplot2.
When I try:

```
install.packages('ggplot2',dependencies = T)
```

I get the following error message:

```
No package called 'Rcpp'  
Error:package or namespace load failed for ggplot2.
```

Then I try:

```
install.packages('Rcpp')
```

I get Rcpp successfully downloaded, but when I try to load ggplot2, I get the same error message:

```
No package called 'Rcpp'  
Error:package or namespace load failed for ggplot2.
```

my session info:

```
R version 3.2.3(2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64(64-bit) 
Running under : Windows >= 8 x64(build 9210) 
locale: [1] Lc_COLLATE = English-United States.1252 LC_CTYPE = English_United  States 1252 [3]LC_MONETARY = English_United States.1252 LC_Numeric =c [5] LC_TIME = English_United States.1252
 attached base packages [1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base loaded via a namespace (and not attached)
 [1] tools_3.2.3 gtable_0.1.2 grid_3.2.3
```

Comment: Could you please give your session details: `sessionInfo()`

Comment: R version 3.2.3(2015-12-10) attached base packages : stats,graphics,grDevice,utils,datasets,methods,base. loaded via a namespace(and not attached):tools_3.2.3,gtable_0.1.2 memoise_0.2.1 grid_3.2.3 digest_0.6.9            I v tried to summarize, would v been better if i could post a screenshot

Comment: no, type  `sessionInfo()` and edit your post with the details: platform, locale parameter, package installed, etc..

Comment: `sessioninfo()  R version 3.2.3(2015-12-10)  Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64(64-bit)  Running under : Windows >= 8 x64(build 9210)  locale:  [1] Lc_COLLATE = English-United States.1252 LC_CTYPE = English_United States 1252  [3]LC_MONETARY = English_United States.1252 LC_Numeric =c  [5] LC_TIME = English_United States.1252  attached base packages  [1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base  loaded via a namespace (and not attached)  [1] tools_3.2.3 gtable_0.1.2 grid_3.2.3`  thats the session info, i have tried installing Rcpp with dependencies but its same error

Answer (score 0):

You need Rtools to install Rcpp. [In the FAQ, page 1](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf).

[here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)

Comment: i have tried installing Rtools, i get a warning message : Rtools is not available (for R version 3.2.3)

Comment: i have installed it, when i check the control pannel Rtools is there but i cant find the package among my list of packages and library(Rtools) doesnt work

Comment: its Rtools 32exe i tried to install, shouldnt that be the file for my version(3.2.3) .

Comment: Rtools is not a package. If it is installed, install both packages rcpp and ggplot2, now.

Comment: thanks so much, i v sorted it, posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

when I tried to install Rcpp
I got the following message :

```
unable to move temporary installation   
C\users\kay\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\file26ec7f366\Rcpp to
C\\users\kay\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\Rcpp
```

the downloaded binary packages are in

```
C:\users\kay\AppData\load\temp\Rtmpkt6uIh\downloaded_packages.
```

I downloaded the zipped file directly from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html
and extracted it directly into:

```
C\users\kay\Documents\R\win-library\3.2
```

this worked. I v got ggplot2 working now.